# Create cut copy paste in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

as i told you before that i am working on graffiti paint api for the printing tool where user can draw edit and update the vector graphics. As per my requirement i need to add a cut copy and paste functionality in my tool so that look more dynamic can anyone help me out to over come this roadblock.

Comment: And as others told you before, try and make sure people get rewarded for helping you...

Comment: how is it possible? can you help me.

Comment: When people answer you and that answer helps you, click on the green tick next to their answer.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many ways. Try this:

Keep an array to keep track of the selected items. I assume you have a selection method.

Keep another array (say clip-board) where temporary items go.

- **Copy** : Add each item of selected array into clip-board Array.
- **Cut** : Add each item of selected array into clip-board Array & remove from stage `removeChild()`.
- **Cut** : Add each item of clip-board Array onto the stage using `addChild()`

If you notice well the clipboard & selected array could be simply one & may not need **Copy** method.