# CTRL + C, CTRL + V and CTRL + X event listener

Tags: flash, flex4, actionscript-3

How to add the event listener on <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> keydown event. I am try the statement as given below on the key down function:

```
public function OnKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent){    
 if((e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode == Keyboard.C)) {  
        trace ("copy");  
    }else if((e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode == Keyboard.V)) {  
        trace ("paste");   
    }else if((e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode == Keyboard.X)) {  
        trace ("cut");
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: The problem would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666068/create-cut-copy-paste-in-as3

Comment: yes loxxy exactly that is the problem

Comment: I'm not sure that everybody should know your entire story, so add links in question please. But anyways, as I can see, you have to add this keydown listener to your tool component upon mouse over and remove in on mouse out events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
systemManager.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);

protected function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.ctrlKey)
            switch(event.keyCode)
            {
                case 67: break;  //Keyboard.C
                case 86: break;  //Keyboard.V
                case 88: break;  //Keyboard.X
            }
}
```

I am using this code.

Comment: Hey, I found it only works when I MUST sure "ENTER" raise before ctrl. However, user operate are very fast, almost raise enter and ctrl at the same time which can not operate as we want. Do you have ever noticed this issue? or you have already solved it.

Comment: This is a memory leak, unless you are removing the listener elsewhere in an appropriate place.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think that it's working Fine:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,onkeydown)

function onkeydown(e:KeyboardEvent)
{

    if(e.ctrlKey)

    {

    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,onkeyup)

    }
}

function onkeyup(e:KeyboardEvent)

{
    if (e.keyCode == 88)

    {
        trace("You pressed Ctrl+X");

    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 67)

    {
        trace("You pressed Ctrl+c");

    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 86 )

    {
        trace("You pressed Ctrl+v");

    }

    e.ctrlKey=false;
}
```